# Use git filter-repo to move a subdirectory to root while retaining files in root

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, git-filter-repo

I am attempting to split up a repository that contains a client and server into two repositories, and I want to move the respective folders to the root while also keeping the files I already had in root - project readmes, `.gitlab-ci.yml`, `.gitignore,` .gitattributes` and so on.

I tried the following line with no luck:

`git filter-repo --path .gitattributes --path .gitignore [...] --subdirectory-filter server`

The result was something I still don't quite understand; the subdir filter seemed to have worked, but whole commits full of changes ended up missing. The above clearly wasn't the correct way to do this, assuming there even is a correct way.

I hacked my way out of it by using separate calls with `--path-rename-match` to first move the root files to the `server` subdir so that they would be moved back to root by a final call with `--subdirectory-filter server`, but that doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: That's because `--subdirectory-filter` is the wrong filter here. You want `--tree-filter` with renaming, probably. Note that this is extremely slow (the `--tree-filter` method is the slowest one) so you might want to look into using `git filter-repo` instead.

Comment: @torek `git filter-repo` instead of ... `git filter-repo` ?

Comment: Oops, `git filter-repo` instead of `git filter-branch`. You're already using the new one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have something similar to the following project structure.

```
client/
server/
.gitlab-ci.yml
.gitignore
```

If you want to extract the client and server directories each to a dedicated project but retain the files in the root directory for each, you could use the `--invert-paths` option.

Using a fresh clone of the original, remove the server directory, set the origin to the new client project and push to the main branch.

```
git filter-repo --path server --invert-paths
```

Take a new clone of the original, remove the client directory, and push to the new server project.

```
git filter-repo --path client --invert-paths
```

If you want to update the path, use `--path-rename`. This could be used to rename a child directory or to move a child directory up in the hierarchy. For example, if you wanted to remove the enclosing `server` directory and move the content to the root of the project.

```
git filter-repo --path-rename server/foo:foo
```

Depending on your structure there are probably more elegant ways to achieve what you're looking for, but a combination of the above should solve for your use case.

Don't forget to process and push any tags you might have as well.

Comment: That is roughly how we went about solving our problem last year, though obviously the details of what exactly we did are a bit hazy by now ;)